# Instantiate objects from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, oop, instance, init

How can I instantiate all the classes for `Year` from a list of tuples `(str, int)` where `str` is the name of a class `Year` and `int` is their age?

```
class Lesson():
    def __init__(self, teacher: Teacher, years: list[tuple[str, int]]) -> None:
        self.teacher = teacher  # teacher is an instance of class Teacher(Person)
        self.year1 = years[0][0](years[0][1]) # year is an instance of class Year(Student)
        self.year2 = years[1][0](years[1][1])
        ...
        self.yearN= years[N][0](years[N][1]) # N can be 1, 2 or maximum 3
```

The classes Student and Year (3 of them) were defined like this

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, age):
        super().__init__(age)
        ...

class Year1(Student):
    def action(self):
        ...

class Year2(Student):
    def action(self):
        ...

class Year3(Student):
    def action(self):
        ...
```

**EDITED**:

In particular, how can I construct a list of objects like this

`[Year1(x), Year2(y), Year3(z)]`

from a list of tuples:

`['Year1', x), ('Year2', y), ('Year3', z)]`

Can I do this?

`self.years= [year[0](year[1]) for year in years]`

Comment: Why on earth would you make them all named variables instead of just storing them as a `list` of the data? `self.students = [Student(name, age) for name, age in students]` (or just `self.students = [Student(*tup) for tup in students]`, whatever floats your boat). If you *ever* find yourself numbering variables beyond about the number 3, you're doing it wrong, use a `list` (or `tuple`, or `dict`, depending on specifics of situation).

Comment: Only after describing the problem I have been struggling with via the OP, I then realised about the list comprehension. Thanks for the tips, @ShadowRanger. Basically, **seeing** the problem helped! Can you please confirm my proposed solution in the edited OP is one of the right way to do it, in particular I don't have to put the `self` in front of the `student[0](student[1])` in the list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first off: If you find yourself numbering variables beyond `3`, *at most*, you're doing it wrong. Use a `list`, `tuple` or `dict` as appropriate.

Secondly: `student[0](student[1])` makes no sense; according to your own type-annotations, `student[0]` is a `str`, and `student[1]` is an `int`. You can't call a `str` as a function with an `int` argument (imagine typing `"foo"(12)` directly; `student[0](student[1])` is exactly equivalent, you just don't see the `str` and `int` as clearly, but it's still never going to work). It seems like you want to make a `Student` object using a name(?) and age(?) argument; you weren't passed the class itself, just the arguments to make it. If a `Student` class exists, accepting a `str` and `int` as arguments to construct it, doing this with a listcomp is your choice of:

```
self.students = [Student(name, age) for name, age in students]
```

or:

```
self.students = [Student(*tup) for tup in students]
```

or if you feel fancy and like more obscure corners of the language:

```
from itertools import starmap  # At top of file

self.students = list(starmap(Student, students))
```

The former is more explicit about what you're doing, and you can reorder or alter the values as you go, the second and third options avoid redundancy (more important as the `tuple`s get larger) and keeps the code as simple as possible. Any of them is infinitely superior to making a variable number of instance attributes on each instance of a class.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the OP to describe the problem in more details. Could you please show me how to instantiate a list of class Year from the list of `tuples('strt, int)` where `str` represents `Year1`, `Year2` or `Year3` and `int` is their age? Thanks

Comment: I've just realised how comprehensive and elegant your answer was. Incredible!